# C# | get/set variable always returning null

Tags: c#, getter-setter

This is the code in a `public static` class:

```
public static string _json { get; set; }

public static string Json
{
    get { return _json; }
    set { 
        _json = Json;
        Console.WriteLine("Json variable was modified. Now it's value is: " + _json);
    }
}
```

Why does it cause a NullReference exception when setting `Json = "{}";` ?

Comment: Your setter should read `_json = value;` Currently, you are always setting the property to the current value of the property.

Comment: The [value keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) is used to define the value being assigned by the set accessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_json = Json;` will invoke the getter again, which returns the (old) value of the backing-field. So your current code is similar to this:

```
public static string get_Json() => _json;
public void set_Json(string value) => 
{
    var newValue = get_Json(); // here _json just returns the old value
    // you don´t use the provided value here
    _json = newValue; 
}
```

You need to use the `value`-keyword:

```
public static string Json
{
    get { return _json; }
    set { 
        _json = value;
        Console.WriteLine("Json variable was modified. Now it's value is: " + _json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setter should assign "value" to the variable, eg

```
set {
    json = value;
    Console.Write...
}
```